# MYSQL Results not updating

Tags: php, mysql, popup, window, updating

I have a button that opens a popup window:

```
<button onclick="loadUsers()">User Accounts</button><br>
```

The loadUsers code is here:

```
    function loadUsers()
    {
        userWindow = window.open("", "_blank", "toolbar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top=0,left=0,width=900,height=405");
        userWindow.document.write("<html><head><link rel='stylesheet'type='text/css' href='css/main.css'><title>Account Management</title></head><body><div class='popup'><?php loadUsersIntoTable(); ?></div></body></html>");
    }
```

As you can see the document calls a PHP function loadUsersIntoTable which connects to a database and retrieves a list of users, then puts it all into a table:

```
//Preloaded function in PHP, will be called later on
        function loadUsersIntoTable()
        {

            require "db.inc";

            //Store the connection in a variable for later use
            $conn = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $dbname);

            //Check for connection
            if(!$conn ){
                die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
            }

            //Define query variable
            $query = "SELECT * FROM users";

            //Start the query
            if($result=mysqli_query($conn,$query))
            {

                //Create our HTML table start here
                echo("<center><table border='1' width='100%'>");
                    echo("<tr>");
                    echo("<th bgcolor='#BABABA'>ID</th>");
                    echo("<th bgcolor='#BABABA'>Name</th>");
                    echo("<th bgcolor='#BABABA'>Telephone</th>");
                    echo("<th bgcolor='#BABABA'>DoB</th>");
                    echo("<th bgcolor='#BABABA'>Address</th>");
                    echo("<th bgcolor='#BABABA'>Country</th>");
                    echo("<th bgcolor='#BABABA'>State</th>");
                    echo("<th bgcolor='#BABABA'>Postcode</th>");
                    echo("<th bgcolor='#BABABA'>Manage</th>");
                    echo("</tr>");

                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                    {

                        //Define all variables we will use
                        $id = $row['ID'];
                        $name = $row['Name'];
                        $telnumber = $row['Tel'];
                        $age = $row['DoB'];
                        $address1 = $row['Address'];
                        $country = $row['Country'];
                        $state = $row['State'];
                        $postcode = $row['Postcode'];

                        echo("<tr>");
                            echo("<td>$id </td>");
                            echo("<td>$name </td>");
                            echo("<td>$telnumber </td>");
                            echo("<td>$age </td>");
                            echo("<td>$address1 </td>");
                            echo("<td>$country </td>");
                            echo("<td>$state </td>");
                            echo("<td>$postcode </td>");
                            echo("<td><form method='POST' ACTION='process_deleteuser.php?id=$id'><input TYPE='submit' VALUE='Delete'></form></td>");
                        echo("</tr>");

                    }

                    mysqli_free_result($result); //Free up memory
                    mysqli_close($conn);

                echo("</table></center>");//Close off table now content has been added

            }
            else
            {
                echo("Unable to retrieve users from database!");
            }
        }
```

However, when I delete one of the accounts, if I close the popup window and reopen it again by the button the account I deleted is still being shown in the HTML table but has been removed from the database.... is there a way around this or to make the popup window refresh each time it's opened so the table refreshes?

Comment: PHP runs on the server ***before*** you output the results to the browser. If you look at the source of your html, you will see that there is no php function there, but the output of that function of when the page was loaded initially. If you need more dynamic results, you need ajax.

Comment: In this situation you need ajax to pop up the latest records after deleting the row.